# Gatling: How to print a regex matched string

Tags: gatling

I want to print a string saved through regex in Gatling.

```
.check(regex("""<(.*)>""").find.saveAs("ViewState"))
```

So I want to print `ViewState` value so that I can check what is saved in it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to view the value, you can retrieve the string from the session and print it like this:

```
   .exec(session => {
      println(session("ViewState").as[String])
      session
   })
```